# Causality and time

Tags: causality

In every instance of A and B (A and B always occur when either occurs), A always comes before B.

In such cases, it can be inferred that A causes (predicts) B.

Does a single instance of B coming before A discredit this?

Consider the alleged theoretical reason against information traveling faster than the speed of light - causality. Consider that in every instance of A and B,  that A comes before B, and then based on this you conclude that A causes B. That is, that A PREDICTS B. But if in one instance B happens before A, there IS a case where B comes before A. Is this sufficient to say that causality has not been established? If so, why is it necessary for A to always come before B in order to say A causes B? By what PROOF does A always have to precede B in every instance in order to establish causality? Is it sufficient to say that, in all instances of A and B, that A almost always has to come before B, to infer causality? Is it established that B can never come before A?

In terms of faster than light travel, A is the information about the launch, travelling at the speed of light, arriving at point X. B is the arrival of the space craft at  X. The theory is that A HAS to occur before B, or the basic inviolate tenants of causality are breached. My ultimate question is, 'is there any proof in statistics that supports this'?

Comment: you stated "A and B". does B happen without A; or A without B?

Comment: Every time I have danced at night, the sun came up the next day.  What powers I must have over the heavens!

Comment: Consider the possibility that there is some other $N$ (which you may not even be aware exists!) that causes $A$ and then causes $B$. While $A$ and $B$ are not causally linked ($N$ just causes each in turn), $B$ always follows $A$. How will you rule out this scenario? Answering that question well will help bridge part of the gap here. [e.g. If I notice that if I see lots of people carrying umbrellas in the morning (even though it's not raining then) then it's almost certain to rain that day, I might imagine that it's at least partly causal, but actually it has no effect at all.]

Comment: Whole books (MANY books) have been written about this. Since you asked on a statistics website, I'd suggest _Causality_ by Judea Pearl. But there's lots of others in statistics and also a bunch in philosophy.

Comment: To clarify, the wording is 'In EVERY instance of A and B, A ALWAYS comes before B'. Thus, every A AND every B occur together. If A occurs, it MUST occur before B, therefore B MUST occur when A occurs.

Comment: It might make sense to migrate this to Philosophy SE.

Comment: Philosophy does not quite fit. 'Statistics' because of the 'probability of B given A' connection. I know what 'conventional' physics says, but it always reverts back to 'time' as being 'linear', 'sequential'. If there are four red socks in a box and one blue one, and I draw out the blue one, what is the probability the next draw is a red sock? Drawing out the blue sock does not 'cause' the next sock to be red, it always WAS red. The CAUSE of the next sock being red was already established from the original composition. Drawing the blue sock didn't cause the remaining socks to turn red.

Comment: @Glen_b, I believe this would be covered by Granger causality. That is, does 'predictive ability' denote 'causality'? And if you arrive at the same usable, useful and meaningful conclusion, that it is almost certain to rain, does it make any difference if it is predictive or causal? In either case, you have a good idea of weather or not to prepare for rain.

Comment: @Justin The difference between predictive and causal is crucial in exactly the way I explained above -- if you try to *directly manipulate* a predictive-but-not-actually-causal variable in order to effect the thing it predicts, you get nowhere. If you want to *use* causality, you have to pull the right lever and past predictive behavior is useless. As an example, an increase or decrease in the number of Catholic priests in a city is reasonably highly predictive of the number of fires per year in that city, but a policy of removing priests will be useless at reducing fires.

Comment: @Glen_b I do not see that requirement in Granger causality. My background is not statistics, but it is germane to my research - causality and time line - does the cause ALWAYS have to appear to occur BEFORE the event?  Thus, if the meaning of 'causality' and 'prediction' is in dispute, this in part addresses the issue.

Comment: My point is that Granger causality is explicitly NOT the same thing as causality. So explaining something that you get with causality but you don't necessarily get with Granger causality would be showing *how* Granger "causality" is not in fact causality in the usual sense. Surely this is not remotely controversial. Granger causality is a useful concept, but we should not read more into the use of the word *causality* in the name than was really intended.

Comment: @Glen_b It is my understanding that there IS controversy over the issue. Guns cause death, but if you eliminate guns, you do not eliminate deaths. Your test  of the existence of causality assumes a one-to-one mapping. It does not allow for other causes. The key is the phrase 'the usual sense'. Granger causality is, well, an unusual sense. That does not make it illegitimate.

Comment: You're completely misrepresenting my position -- indeed you seem quite determined to argue with people instead of coming any closer to understanding the issues. While it's of no great concern to me whether you care to understand the various issues with the question I am trying to convey (a number of mistaken premises), it brings you no closer to having an open question.

Comment: @Glen_b, my question is specific and clear, unambiguous, and clearly in the realm of statistics. It has an unambiguous answer, if a proof exists. Perhaps the reason for my being put on hold, is that the posters on this site just don't know, and do not want to admit it. Another presentation of the question: given events A and B, where A comes before B, statistics has considered P(B|A). My question is, why not P(A|B)? Is this just ASSUMED to be absurd, or is it PROVEN to be absurd? Remember, Granger causality was assumed to be absurd until applications were discovered, THEN people wanted proof.

Comment: As far as I know, the idea that causality flows unidirectionally in time is taken as an axiom, it's not proven using statistics. Philosophers work on choosing the axioms. Statistics gives us tools to learn about particular causal relationships, when the axioms apply. If you are a time traveler, we shouldn't assume our methods work on you. :) 

We do know that causation can be simultaneous - e.g. the simultaneous transfer of information between entangled particles in quantum physics. So on the quantum scale, the statistical tools we use to learn about causation would no longer work.

Comment: @Lizzie Silver simultaneous causation also applies when you put two balloons in a box that is larger than one but not larger than both. Each balloon simultaneously deforms the other as they are pushed in. It's not  one balloon goes in, and the other forms around it. Newtons' Law is also simultaneous causation. I suspected it was an axiom in statistics, but I still need it clarified.  I find it regarded as an assumption not an axiom. Axioms have surprises. 1=1 is an axiom (equality) but 10=9.999999... is provable by math and routine assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the event "a hurricane warning is issued", and $B$ "a hurricane arrives." In the past X years, $A$ has always preceded $B$, because the weather service is pretty good. Does $A$ cause $B$?

Comment: Yes, in the sense of [Granger causality](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Granger_causality).

Comment: @Aksakal That merely serves to demonstrate that "Granger causality" *is not causality*, at least not in anything like the usual sense. If the weather service now attempted to prevent hurricanes by no longer predicting any, they'd fail, horribly -- while if it was causal in anything like the usual sense, it should succeed.  Granger causality is a jargon term with an entirely different meaning to the usual thing "causality" is taken to mean. It's a useful concept in its intended application area, but we should be careful not to conflate it with causality in what seems to be the intended sense.

Comment: Without experiments it's impossible to establish causality based on solely observations.

Comment: Regarding Granger causality, what is the difference between 'predictability' and 'causality'? If A always predicts B, and always comes before B, then does the existence of A cause B?